# Inserindo data-id e data-url no campo extra do DataTable

Tags: front-end, jquery-datatables

Vejam esse código

https://github.com/rg3915/frontend/blob/master/djfront/djbasic/templates/djbasic/customer_list_datatable.html#L53

```
defaultContent: '<i  class="fa fa-close pull-right js-customer-delete"style="color: #0066FF; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; margin-left:10px"data-id=""data-url=""></i> <i  class="fa fa-edit pull-right js-customer-edit"style="color: #0066FF; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer"data-id=""data-url=""></i>'
```

Eu consigo inserir uma coluna extra no DataTable com o valor que eu quiser.

Dai eu consegui inserir uma classe no 'tr' (que é um `row`)...

https://github.com/rg3915/frontend/blob/master/djfront/djbasic/templates/djbasic/customer_list_datatable.html#L58

```
$(row).addClass('tr-customer');
```

Mas não consigo inserir um 'data-id' e 'data-url' nesse 'row'.

Já tentei

`$(row).data('id', 'valor_qualquer')`

Mas ele não insere.

**Pergunta:** como eu insiro um 'data-id' e 'data-url' dentro do 'tr' proveniente do DataTable?

Resultado esperado:

`<tr class="tr-customer" data-id="" data-url=""></tr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir o atributo utilize a função attr() do Jquery:

```
$(row).attr('data-id', 'valor_qualquer');
```

Para recuperar este valor, acesse o atributo da seguinte forma:

```
$(row).data('id');
```